# AIX sudo rootsh

Tags: sudo, sh, aix

I'm allowed to do:

```
sudo /usr/bin/rootsh   -i -u user
```

Additionally I want do something like:

```
echo 'date' | sudo /usr/bin/rootsh   -i -u user
```

Here I get the answer:

```
no tty/pty on stdin: Not a typewriter
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure if you are able to make that work. rootsh as I understand from the manuals are made function as a wrapper. Taken from the man-page
"rootsh - a logging wrapper for shells"

This makes me think that it tries to take control over the terminal and not "stdin".

But feel free to correct me.

Comment: What version of rootsh are you running?

Comment: Where looking at the source-code at https://sourceforge.net/p/rootsh/code/ci/master/tree/src/rootsh.c

Version 1.5.4 should work, as far I can understand from the code at row 363. 

Im not a user myself. But if possible, please provide version number